# best practice for changing GameObject behaviour between parents?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game object that i need to move around in the scene.
Every time the game object is under a different parent it should behave differently in just one little aspect of its existance.
For example, let say i have a dog, when it is under a kid parent, the dog should play.
If the dog game object is move to be under the adult parent, it should bark.  etc...
My solution at first was to use if-else and check under which parent the dog is being used.
And by knowing the parent i can invoke the correct method of dog action.
But that approach is very ugly, and not very scalable.
I would like to maybe do something more polymorphic, and maybe create multiple dog classes, one for barking, one for playing, etc, and than somehow instantiate a new game object with different script every time the owner of the dog changes.
What is the best practice for such a thing?
No need to mention that i have many game objects that are switching their respective parents so i need a systematic solution.
Thank yous

Comment: Have a look on delegates, you would then update the method that must be used every time a change occurs.
This video explains it well, see the Modular Delegate section : https://youtu.be/3ZfwqWl-YI0?t=940

Comment: I believe that is [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) what you want ... share your code to get more help

Comment: I strongly recommend you to watch [youtube video about strategy pattern by Christopher Okhravi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9ejT8FO-7I&list=PLrhzvIcii6GNjpARdnO4ueTUAVR9eMBpc&ab_channel=ChristopherOkhravi), understand the strategy pattern it's exactly what you need

Comment: Thank you, i watched it, it's very good. So please tell me if i got it right.
Basically every time the dog is changing owner i need to replace the script component the represent the behaviour?

Comment: On second thought, maybe it's better to have IAction interface member field in the Dog class, and then instantiate a new Action class (ex. PlayAction, BarkAction) and set the member variable to it?